# Remove duplicates working for one field but not for multiple JS/VUEJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vueapp which pulls in some JSON data via an axios request

I am trying to remove duplicates and caps in my results. If I do this for one 'attendances' it works fine but if I try to do it with the other data (which looks the same ) it does not work and also breaks the page.

Im pretty stuck on what this could be. The error in the console is

**cannot Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')**

JSON

```
    "Data": {
    "date": "Sep 2022,Sep 2022,",
    "location": "AB,AB,",
    "attendance": "daily,daily,weekly,daily,weekly,monthly,"
    },
    "Data": { 
    "date": "Oct 2021 - Sep 2022,Oct 2021 - Sep 2022,Oct 2021 - Sep 2022,Sep 2024,Sep 2024,",
    "location": "AB,AB,CD,EF,EF,EF,", 
    "attendance": "daily,daily,weekly,Weekly," 
    },
......
```

**HTML**

```
  <div v-if="location">
                  <strong>Location:</strong>
                  {{ location }}
                </div>    
         <div v-if="attendance">
                  <strong>Attendance:</strong>
                  {{ attendance }}
                </div>
```

Method in my vue results component

```
    props: {
        result: Object,
      },
      data: function () {
        return {       
          startdate: this.Data.startdate,       
          location: this.Data.location,
           },

 methods: {
    removeDuplicates() {
      const attendances = [];
      this.Data.attendance.split(",").forEach((a) => {
        if (attendances.indexOf(a) == -1 && a !== "") {
           attendances.push(a);
        }
      });
      //console.log("attendances : " + attendances )
      this.attendance = attendances.join(", ");
  
      // const locations = [];
      // this.Data.location.split(",").forEach((l) => {
      //   if (locations.indexOf(l) == -1 && l !== "") {
      //     locations.push(l);
      //   }
      // });
      // this.location = locations.join(", ");
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.removeDuplicates();
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: you are probably calling `removeDuplicates` while `this.Data.attendance` is undefined - where is the code that populates `this.Data`?

Comment: The JSON looks like multiple `Data` keys are present. So you are targeting the wrong variable. Install Vue Developer Tools for your browser to see the component's data more easily.

Comment: That JSON looks like it is invalid. My guess what you are showing is not what you actually have,. Is it an array of objects? Because an object can not have the same key more than once.

Comment: @Jaromanda X - the code displays on the page but the whole array inc. all the duplicates. I have updated my question to show where the data is pulled in. I hope this helps you to help me. Thank you!

Comment: @epascarello - I had changed the JSON data as I don't want to show my actual data. I realized I had an extra couple of " which I have removed now. Thank you

Comment: Your code is `{ Data: {}, Data: {} }` which is probably not what you have....

Comment: This is correct but I have not included the main wrapper but that's just as I dont want to show too much code.

Comment: one of your Data objects must not have an `attendance` property.  simply add an `if` statement checking for the property before performing any operations on it like `split()`.  if the property does not exist, loop to the next object.